# How to get the value store in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am storing userId at the time of registration in SharedPreferencesand. Now I want to access the SharedPreferences stored UserId value. Till now I tried this code:

```
prefrence = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
edit3 = prefrence.edit();
edit3.putInt("user_id", userid);
Log.e("Commit", "SharedPreferences");
edit3.commit();
```

And on the next activity I am using this for access:

```
prefr = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

value = prefr.getInt("user_id", "");
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: On a side note, `Log.e()` should be used to log errors, not generic debug messages like committing preference value. You'd better use `Log.d()` instead.

Comment: @keaukraine yeh..but I personally like Log.e() as it shows message in RED color.

Comment: check out this, [ans][1]. hope this will help u.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20897014/793943

Comment: thanks i got the solution and resolve

Answer (score 4):

You PUT in an INT and GET a STRING... Maybe that's causing a type cast error.

I see you changed your code, to get an int... the WRONG WAY!

You are doing so:

```
value = prefr.getInt("user_id", "");
```

Instead you should do so:

```
value = prefr.getInt("user_id", 0);
```

(You can't assign "" to an int.)

The above is valid **if user_id is an int**. **If user_id is a string**, then you should do a putString and a getString. Like:

```
edit3.putString("user_id", userid);
```

And then

```
value = prefr.getString("user_id", "");
```

So you grant the necessary type consistency.

Comment: Yep, `prefr.getInt("user_id", "")` shouldn't compile. There's no such overloaded `getInt()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
prefr.getString("user_id", "");
```

to

```
prefr.getInt("user_id", 0);
```